# Add a text link to WooCommerce Checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce on a wordpress installation. I have also purchased the plugin woocommerce-checkout-field-editor-pro to create custom fields on the checkout form.

My problem is, while the WooCommerce Checkout Field Editor Pro plugin is great, it does not allow me to just add a text link. It allows a label, but no way of making that label a link.

If I can just figure out where the custom label field gets stored when its created I am thinking I can just wrap it in an `<a href >` tag to turn it into a hyper link. But I can't figure out where the field is stored. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A few template files make up the checkout page and can be found in:

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout

The files which may be of most interest to you could be either form-checkout.php or review order.php.

Inside your own theme folder, create a folder called woocommerce and copy across any files you want to edit, making sure to place them inside the exact folder structure they are kept within Woocommerce. So in this case, copy the files to your_theme/woocommerce/templates/checkout/.  Any changes made to these files will override the original template.

You can edit the templates and add, or remove, any code as you need to.

Comment: Please not the path is yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php (no template folder) per the notes in the file